# Running set of sql queries like a cron job in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a legacy database which contains all data and i have seperate queries which i run to retrieve data .

What i would like to do is run a set of sql statements and cache data on django but i only want to run it when the server is restarted or cache is cleared.

could anyone tell me where should put these sql statement init.py ?

Comment: Is the cache cleared on a schedule? Is the legacy data time sensitive?

Comment: Yes, the cache is cleared weekly, daily in some cases. And yes there is always data being imported into the database